# backgroundMessageHandler IOS does not fire on low power mode [rnFireBase]

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

So it seems that react native Firebase has a background method for listening to messages.
however nowhere in the DOCS does it mention anything about low-power mode on IOS.
This is a big issue because The message handler never fires. My app relies on notifications to trigger foreground data refresh...

Answer (score 0):

Low power mode on iOS disables a number of device features. One of those is the receipt of push notification as the push notification service requires that the device keeps a persistent connection to Apple's servers. This consumes battery.

Firebase relies on push notifications to receive updates.

There is nothing you can do about this.

Generally you can expect pending push notifications to be delivered once the device exits low power mode, but there is no guarantee that push notifications will always be delivered and your app should have other mechanisms for checking for updated data.

Comment: thank you for that information.  Would you have a clue as to how to handle foreground data refresh?  let's say you get a notification for friend request in the background. The user goes into the app and nothing is there.